# Extracting list elements satisfying a property

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

My understanding is that Mathematica code executes faster when a list is operated on in a functional way (avoiding copies or splitting up the list).

I coded the following to toy with this idea, extracting the elements from a list of integers that satisfy a test-property (say Mod[x,7] == 0)

```
multiples7Test[x_] := (Mod[x, 7] == 0);
myMapIndexed[f_, x_List] := MapIndexed[{f[#1], #2} &, x];
trueCase[x_] := TrueQ[x[[1]]];
pairs[x_] := myMapIndexed[multiples7Test, x];
multiples7Positions[x_] := Position[pairs[x], {_, {_}}?trueCase];
multiples7[x_] := Extract[x, multiples7Positions[x]]
```

multiples7[Range[30]] produces {7, 14, 21, 28}.

Such code seems to stay close to the "whole-list" approach to gain efficiency. Presumably there is a Mathematica function that efficiently produces a list of elements (from a list of integers) satisfying a given property? I'd like to compare the speeds of various options to check how far the above code is off the (no doubt) highly optimised Mathematica version.

Comment: What about `Select[Range[30], Mod[#, 7] == 0 &]` ?

Comment: Thanks will check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider the following base case:

```
list = Range[1000000];
AbsoluteTiming[base = multiples7[list];]
```

> {2.34272, Null}

If at all possible, vectorize the test. Consider the following case with `Select`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[res1 = Select[list, Mod[#, 7] == 0 &];]
res1 == base
```

> {0.579586, Null}
>
> True

If we instead use `Mod` on the list instead of each element on the list:

```
AbsoluteTiming[res2 = Pick[#, Mod[#, 7], 0]&[Range[1000000]];]
res2 == base
```

> {0.009911, Null}
>
> True

From the inside out, `Mod[#, 7]` (where `#` is the range 1-1000000) finds the modulus of each element of the range without needing to call `Mod` as a function just shy of a million extra times. This is pretty much the entirety of the time savings. `Pick` is then used to pick everything from the whole range where the modulus turned out to be 0, and is quite fast.

So, if possible, write the test such that it can be vectorized over the whole range you are using it on. Otherwise for a large test range even just calling a simple function a few million times can be a huge time sink.

Also, if possible, consider filtering the range to exclude known bad candidates or constructing it so as to minimize the number of bad candidates from the get go.

```
AbsoluteTiming[res3 = Range[7, 1000000, 7];]
res3 == base
```

> {0.000111, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Thanks eyorble. Can you clarify what "write the test such that it can be vectorized over the whole range" means? I am not sure how to interpret vectorized in this context. I looked up Pick in the language documentation, so have some idea of what vectorized could mean, but it is not sharp enough for me to apply it in other contexts.

Comment: In this context, vectorized means that the function can automatically map itself over the whole list, as in `Mod[list, 7]` automatically applying itself to each member of `list` automatically, and preferably also be evaluated using vectorized functions. To me, `Pick` isn't the prime example of the vectorization here, it's just a really fast way to pick from one list using another as a selector.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that vectorizable is indicated by "Listable" in Mathematica? That would make sense and help me to identify the cases where we can assume speedy application of an operation to the whole list.

Comment: `Listable` is going to be the key property to avoiding needing to call the function extra times based on the length of the list, so it should always help with this, yes. Vectorization can refer to a bit more based on how the list actually gets handled at the lower levels, but that's something for `Compile` if you're going that far. I would expect that `Listable` has most of the gains, but without a less toy example it's probably harder to say.

Comment: Thanks, wonderful answer. It's a bit of a climb to assimilate Mathematica, but loving every step of it. Another insight gained, thanks again.